# Where to Edit DNN Registration Message

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have came to different places in my DNN but I wasnt able to locate the message that says

> (Note: - Registration may take several seconds. Once you click the
>   Register button please wait until the system responds.)

What I was able to locate is the message that says :

> Note: Membership to this website is Verified. Once your account information has been submitted, you will receive an email containing a
>   link that you can use to verify your account.All fields marked with a
>   red asterisk are required.

this message is located at `\App_GlobalResources`

Can anyone tell me where can I find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be found in the language editor under

```
local resources/desktopmodules/admin/security/app_localresources/register.ascx
```

That controls the Register module.

Comment: This is it.. Thank you. You saved me hours of looking for it.